# "One thing or another" is singular or plural?

Tags: grammaticality

There are a lot of answers about has/have but I couldn't find one that answers my question.

Which one is correct ?

> Window size or position **has** been modified
>
> Window size or position **have** been modified

I guess that if the `or` was exclusive I should use `has`. But there, the window size and position can be both modified at the same time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you would take the "maximum".
Just like math, you can develop -> size, position, size and position.

As there is a possible 'and' (plural), this is the correct grammar:

> **have** been modified